# Google maps marker show just one quarter of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, google-maps, canvas, gmaps4rails

I am working with gmaps4rails gem, and when generating the map, I get this weird behavior in the markers:

[image: Quarter marker]

As you can see the marker shows just one part of it, and I don't understand why.  If I use the default pin, the marker is shown correctly.

How can I know which CSS is the marker/map using? Or, any thoughts how can I solve this?

You can see it live here: [Gmaps borked](http://gentle-cloud-4082.herokuapp.com/maps)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the used markerImage-definition, I guess the size-argument has a wrong value.

Comment: I would love to provide you with that. I can't find that info in the code of the HTML page though.  How can I find that?

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Either that, or it's on a tile boundary and `optimized` is not `false`. Hommer: post a link if necessary (and use a link-shrinker like tinyurl.com to hide your domain name if necessary)

Comment: Sure: http://gentle-cloud-4082.herokuapp.com/maps -- I actually started a new rails app from scratch to avoid having any css conflicts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the width-and height-properties for the marker-setup.

Use this:

```
{"description": "", 
 "title": "", 
 "sidebar": "", 
 "lng": "-122.345467", 
 "lat": "37.568749", 
 "picture": "assets/prova.png", 
 "width": 70, 
 "height": 88}
```

also add a marker_anchor-member to the setup to keep the marker pinned at the correct position:

```
"marker_anchor":[23,78]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That shows the pin yes. However, when I zoom out, the pin ends up being in the sea.  Is that because the pin is too big I assume?